# Создать функцию, которая выводит слова сообщения в алфавитном порядке

Tags: c++

Начинающий в c++  и даже понятия не имею как можно выполнить данную функцию

Comment: Выполнить функцию - просто: SomeFunc(); и функция выполнится!

Comment: Вы бы все-таки зашли на страничку с правилами, как задавать вопрос на форуме, пока громкий смех не пошел по Интернетам

Answer (score 2):

Всё зависит от того, какого типа ваше сообщение. Приведу пример для string :

```
void printSorted(std::string str);

int main()
{
    std::string str = "aba caba baba";
    printSorted(str);
}

void printSorted(std::string str)
{
    int i=0; int j=0;
    std::vector<std::string> to_sort;
    while (i<str.length())
    {
        while (i<str.length() && str[i]==' ') { i++; continue;}
        if (i>=str.length()) {break;}
        j = i;
        while (i<str.length() && str[i]!=' ') i++;
        to_sort.push_back( str.substr(j, i-j) );
        i++;
    }
    std::sort(to_sort.begin(), to_sort.end());
    for (std::string i : to_sort)
        std::cout<<i<<" ";
}
```

Comment: void ABCOrder(char *s)
А как например если функция задана так ?

Comment: вы на С пишете или на С++? И на будущее, прочтите вот это, пожалуста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: С++, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
//нужны всего 4 строки кода
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<string> sms;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<std::string>  I;
    copy( I(cin), I(), inserter(sms, sms.begin()));
    //тут вместо cin может быть любой входной поток
    for (string s : sms)  cout << s <<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```